# MS Access 2013 saved append query not updating all fields

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a saved query, qryInsertLog which is as follows:

```
PARAMETERS UserIDPar Long, UnitIDPar Long, LogEntryPar LongText, FNotesPar LongText;
INSERT INTO tblLogBook ( UserID, UnitID, LogEntry, FNotes )
SELECT [UserIDPar] AS Expr1, [UnitIDPar] AS Expr2, [LogEntryPar] AS Expr3, [FNotesPar] AS Expr4;
```

I'm trying to run this query when a save button is clicked on an unbound form, where the parameters are gathered from the form controls. My VBA code for the save button is:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim okToSave As Boolean

If Me.cboUser.Value = 0 Or IsNull(Me.cboUser.Value) Then
    MsgBox "You must choose a user. Record not saved."
    okToSave = False
ElseIf Me.cboUnit.Value = 0 Or IsNull(Me.cboUnit.Value) Then
    MsgBox "You must choose a unit. Record not saved."
    okToSave = False
ElseIf Me.txtLogEntry.Value = "" Or IsNull(Me.txtLogEntry.Value) Then
   MsgBox "You must have somtehing to log. Record not saved."
    okToSave = False
Else
    okToSave = True
End If

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryInsertLog")

qdf.Parameters("UserIDPar").Value = Me.cboUser.Value
qdf.Parameters("UnitIDPar").Value = Me.cboUnit.Value
qdf.Parameters("LogEntryPar").Value = Me.txtLogEntry.Value
qdf.Parameters("FNotesPar").Value = IIf(IsNull(Me.txtFNotes.Value), "", Me.txtFNotes.Value)

If okToSave Then
     qdf.Execute
End If

qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

When this code is run, the FNotes field of the table isn't updated. The other three fields update as expected. FNotes is the only field which isn't required. I hardcoded a string for FNotes paramater like so:

```
qdf.Parameters("FNotesPar").Value = "why doesn't this work"
```

rather than using the form control value, and got the same result: that field just doesn't update. When I run this query from the Access Objects window and supply parameter values from the prompts, it works just fine. When I create form that's bound to the table, it also seems to work just fine.

I can't figure out why there's no trouble updating the LogEntry field but the FNotes field fails to update.

Comment: You have parameter query issues. No luck with last one either? Check your values using debug.print. Add a dbFailonError to your Execute.

Comment: I bet it's the LongText parameters again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the new record via a `DAO.Recordset` instead of a `DAO.QueryDef`.

First, include this declaration ...

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
```

Then use this after `Set db = CurrentDb` ....

```vb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblLogBook")
With rs
    If okToSave Then
        .AddNew
        !UserID = Me.cboUser.Value
        !UnitID = Me.cboUnit.Value
        !LogEntry = Me.txtLogEntry.Value
        !FNotes = Nz(Me.txtFNotes.Value, "")
        .Update
    End If
    .Close
End With
```

Note `Nz(Me.txtFNotes.Value, "")` gives you the same thing as `IIf(IsNull(Me.txtFNotes.Value), "", Me.txtFNotes.Value)`, but more concisely.